# Separate controls bar from video content area in JWPlayer

Tags: html, css, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer to play my videos. Is there anyway to separate the controls bar from video content as below design:

[image]

Or any ways to add a margin/padding to create this white space.
I tried to inspect that object to change css but maybe it's a block[image]

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: can you please share the working example if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controlbar remain inside the player div, but we can change width and height of each element inside the div.

This is a first example: 
http://codepen.io/fdambrosio/pen/rmJGrq

html:

```
<body class="playerpage">
  <div id='divplayer'></div> 
</body>
```

css:

```
.playerpage #divplayer {
    background-color: white;
}
.playerpage video.jw-video {
    width: 400px ;
    height: 200px ;
}
.playerpage .jw-controlbar {
    width: 450px ;
    left: 50px ;
}
```

js:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("divplayer"); 
playerInstance.setup({
file:'//video...',
width: 544, 
height: 306
});
```

Another solution is to build a custom controlbar using JS API, so you can use that controlbar where you want

Comment: Thank you. I tried another simple way, that using an empty div with white background to insert that position. :D